# Adobe Analytics: Hit-based Exclusion Segment Allowing Entries

Tags: adobe-analytics, web-analytics

In this example, I have a PROP that collects "Page Type" Let's say it's Prop10
Pathing is enabled on this PROP

I've created a segment to exclude a certain value from Prop10. This is a simple segment with no containers, just an exclude for the value of "Site Section 1"

When I run a report for Prop10 using "Visits" as the metric and apply this segment, "Site Section 1" is excluded from results

However, if I run a report for "Prop10 Entries" or other Pathing-based reports while the segment is applied, "Site Section 1" does show in results

Since this is a Hit-based segment, and the entry hit does have a Prop10 value of "Site Section 1", why would this not be suppressed by the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Entry Prop10" is actually visit-based; it persists throughout the entire visit on the backend. So while you'd be excluding the hits where it was initially defined, the persisted values still appear in subsequent hits in the visit.